# show integrability of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be iid random variable with $E[X_i]=0$ and $P(X_i>0)>0$. Let $S_0=x>0$ and define $S_n=S_0+\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. Then define $T=\inf\{n \geq 0: S_n \leq 0 \text{ or } S_n \geq b\}$. I have shown that $T$ has finite expectation, and am trying to show $X_T$ is integrable. Any hint or help would be great!

Comment: You probably need to assume that the $X_i$ are integrable also

Comment: Try writing $X_T = \Sigma_{i = 0}^{\infty} 1_{T = i} X_i$ and compute the L1 norm...

Comment: @AreaMan It is assumed that $\mathbb E[X_i]=0$.

Comment: Since the $X_i$ are i.i.d. with finite expectation and $\mathbb E[T]<\infty$, Wald's identity yields 
$$
\mathbb E[S_T] = \mathbb E[S_1]\mathbb E[T] = S_0\mathbb E[T]<\infty.
$$

Comment: @Math1000 but how does this emply $E[|X_{T}|]< \infty$?

Comment: It does not, I misread the question. Since for all $n$ $$|X_{n\wedge T}|\leqslant\max\{S_0, b\} $$ with probability $1$, it follows from optional stopping that $\mathbb E[X_T]=\mathbb E[X_0]=0$.